# Unable to configure RollingFileAppender to the root logger since its name is an empty string

Tags: logging, log4j2

Unable to configure RollingFileAppender to the root logger since its name is an empty string. I am experiencing this issue only in Log4j2 2.20.0 library. It was working earlier without any issue. I really appreciate your help on this!

It is throwing NullPointerException.

I have tried reverting back to the previous version and it works but I need to upgrade the library to the latest version.